# Custom CListCtrl

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

I need to create a ListControl in MFC, each row having different number of columns.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible.  The workaround is trivial, just don't put any text in the sub-item.

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to my guru's(Chris Maunder-Codeproject founder) article:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/gridctrl.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use custom-draw List Control. Then you can specify maximum columns for the control, but draw only specified number of columns in each row. You can fill unwanted columns with a background color. [Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364048%28VS.80%29.aspx#customdraw_topic4) a sample of how you could create custom-draw list control.